# Cannot make child element the same height as parent element IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to make a child element of a table cell take on the table cell's height and width using CSS.  Here is the html:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="yellowDiv"></div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
    table tbody tr td:nth-child(1){
        position: relative;
    }

    table tbody tr td div.yellowDiv{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: yellow;
    }
```

The above code renders properly in Chrome, but not in IE (only concerned with IE 9 and 10).  I have also tried setting `display: table-cell;` for the `div` element but to no avail.  I have also tried setting the height of the `div` element to be 100% but that has not worked either.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutey-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout. They have their own layout context. Therefore they cannot know how big their parent element is.

You need to use JavaScript to solve this or consider why you need absolute positioning at all.

You can use:

```
.yellowDiv {
    background-color:#ffff00;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't need absolute positioning.  I need for the child element to have the same width and height of its parent element.  I used absolute positioning in an attempt to achieve this, because that is what I had seen in other similar questions.

Comment: While it's true absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow, their reference for positioning and sizing is the nearest positioned parent element. If its parent is relatively positioned and has a size, then the absolutely positioned element will reference that size when using percent. Javascript isn't needed at all.